# Laptop keeps shutting down while updating or download from store

Tags: upgrade, updates, ubuntu-store

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E5520. Hardware is i7 2nd Gen, 500 GB Hard Disk, and 8 GB Ram. I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I have been using this laptop with Windows 10 for quite some time now with no issue whatsoever. Just recently for development purposes, I have started dual booting my system with Ubuntu.

But now I am facing random shutdown issues in Ubuntu, though it's still running fine on Windows 10. Shutdowns are occurring when I try to update or download something new from store. However, if I use terminal to update or download, then there is no issue.

I tried to research random shutdown problems, but all of those were related to hardware issues or overheating, which is not the issue for me as I am still using Windows 10 with no issue. Even Ubuntu works, as long as I don't download or update something.

Recently I downloaded Spotify from store and the laptop suddenly gave me popup for shutdown, and even when I click cancel on the dialog it still shuts down in next 3-5 secs.

So if anyone have any suggestion for me please do tell me. I don't know what to do anymore.

Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "popup for shutdown." Exactly what does the popup say? Exactly which release of Ubuntu are you running? Is the system plugged in or on battery when these shutdowns happen?

Comment: I guess that what the OP means is the dialog "Suspend | reboot| Shutdown"

Comment: @user535733 its the Power Off dialog, which comes when we press shutdown. it has three options, Cancel, Restart and Power Off and the version is 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you saying that it's the standard Gnome power off dialog that says "The system will poweroff in 60 seconds" with three options: Cancel / Restart / Power Off? Or a different poweroff dialog? Note the *exact* time of an occurrence, and review /var/log/syslog for the few seconds before and after. If you don't understand the log, then post the relevant minute of log activity in your question.

Comment: Machine shutdown is probably done by BIOS/ACPI, to protect the machine. You say it’s not hardware but I think the fan control is somehow messed up when running Ubuntu, causing CPU or something else to overheat and triggering shutdown.